# DataGridView bound to BindingList displays empty rows

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, bindinglist

This code causes `DataGridView grid` to display empty rows although it has a column with `DataPropertyName` set to "MyProp1":

```
public class MyClass
{
  public int MyProp1;
  public int MyProp2;
  public int MyProp3;
}

public class MyItems:IListSource
{
  BindingList<MyClass> _items = new BindingList<MyClass>();

  //..............................

  //IListSource
  public bool ContainsListCollection
  {
      get { return false; }
  }

  //IListSource
  public System.Collections.IList GetList()
  {
      return _items;
  }
}

MyItems i = new MyItems();
.............
//MyItems list is populated
.............
grid.DataSource = i;
```

What could be wrong?

If I make a DataTable with "MyProp1" column, its contents is displayed the right way.

Comment: Why `ContainsListCollection` returns `false` in getter?

Comment: Can you post the XAML for your datagridview?

Comment: Is it `WPF` or `WinForms`? If your collection elements are `IList` the return must be true otherwise false.

Comment: @Alireza posted solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to change the public fields of `MyClass` to properties:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int MyProp1 { get; set; }
   public int MyProp2 { get; set; }
   public int MyProp3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It helped! Now it works even with `List<T>` instead of `BindingList<T>` and `true` or `false` in `ContainsListCollection` doesn't make any difference.